# How can we consume the Binary Content using Tridion CD OData web service?

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, odata

I have found the SO Link which discusses about downloading the binary variant using OData service by using the HTTP URL as below,

[http://localhost:82/odata.svc/BinaryContents(BinaryId=159,PublicationId=4,Varia‌ntId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')/$value](http://localhost:82/odata.svc/BinaryContents(BinaryId=159,PublicationId=4,Varia%E2%80%8CntId='Y29uZmlnLWJvb3RzdHJhcA==')/$value)

We would like to consume the binarycontent using C# client, I am stuck in converting the above HTTP OData Request to the equivalent C# LINQ Query and consume the BinaryVariant via C#.

Here is what I have done so far,

```
    BinaryContent content = (from s in cds.BinaryContents
                             where s.BinaryId == 1415 && s.PublicationId == 3 && s.VariantId == "ZGlzdC1jb21wb25lbnRzLmh0bWw="
                             select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

But the BinaryContent class does not have a method/property to return the byte[] or data stream.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a way to do this using just the LINQ API, but you can download the file as a byte[] using the `System.Net.WebClient` object.

Try this:

```
string url = cds.BinaryContents.RequestUri + "(BinaryId=1415 ,PublicationId=3,VariantId='ZGlzdC1jb21wb25lbnRzLmh0bWw=')/$value";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + OdataUtilities.GetAccessToken());
byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
```

Note that you only need the line 'webClient.Headers.Add' part if you are using a secured OData Service. `OdataUtilities.GetAccessToken()` is just a method I use to retrieve a token for the request.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will give  a try.
But from the look of it, because we are able to access byte[] via HTTP Odata URL, byte[] property is available in the BinaryContent class, but currently it might not be a public property of that class.